# Problem with \graphicspath and path names on Windows

Tags: graphics, errors

I define a path in a variable: `\newcommand{\myfolder}[0]{c:/folder1/folder2}`

```
\input{\myfolder/file1.tex} works

\includegraphics{\myfolder/images/dummypic1.png} works.
```

If I use `\graphicspath{{\myfolder/images}}` then `\includegraphics{dummypic1.png}` fails.

The reason is, that \graphicspath adds a blank after `\myfolder` which causes `\myfolder/dummypic1.png` to expand to `"c:/folder1/folder2 /image/dummypic1.png"`

Obviously `\input` or `\includegraphic` do not add the blank
This behavior is new with the last update, previous versions worked as expected.

Minimal example

```
\newcommand{\myfolder}[0]{c:/folder1/folder2}

\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,twoside,footsepline,headsepline,a4paper,final]{scrbook} %draft 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\graphicspath{{\myfolder/images}}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{\myfolder/images/dummypic1.png} % works

\includegraphics{dummypic1.png} % fails


\end{document}
```

Thanks for the help with the great module.
Othmar

Version graphics 66204 in Texlive 2023

Comment: A patch went to ctan yesterday that should fix that

Comment: It works for me with todays update of l3kernel.

Comment: Many thanks! Indeed it works again as before.